# How can I multiply lookup values from two different tables and then sum them in just one cell?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup, sumproduct

I am trying to get a dedicated material table in excel. So we have a few products and these products require particular materials. I know how much and which materials go in particular products. I also know how much is sold in which year, now I want to calculate the required materials for these years. Because the productbase is large (>100), and thus >100 columns, I would like to use some lookup or index function to automate the multiplication.

As shown in the picture, I tried using a sumproduct, which was also explained in some other question on stackoverflow. This sumproduct should multiply all values obtained in one table with the corresponding values in the other. I feel that something is not right about my first two match functions (see picture again)

[image]

```
The code used:
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($B$19:$E$22;MATCH(B$2;$A$19:$A$22;0);MATCH(B$10;$B$18:$E$18;0));INDEX($B$3:$E$5;MATCH($A11;$A$3:$A$5;0);MATCH(TRUE;$B$3:$E$5>0;0)))
```

The image contains some extra info and explanation of the actual need

The reason that it needs a lookup or index is because the products in table 3 are always in another order than what is shown in table 1.

I would like to have this sumproduct as automated as possible, thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and adapt the below:

[image]

Formula in `B11`:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A11,$A$1:$A$5,0)):INDEX($E:$E,MATCH($A11,$A$1:$A$5,0))*TRANSPOSE(B$19:B$22))
```

Entered as array, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag right and down into matrix.

***Side-note:*** Be sure to edit your question to include all relevant information, including your own atempted formula, as text. Way easier to copy paste sample data that has been formatted as markdown :)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your fast answer! This is already way closer to the answer for my problem! I will try working with your proposal. There is still one minor thing; by transposing table 3 I might multiply the wrong P values from table 3 and table 1. In this example they are on the same column-row, however, in the actual sheet they might be in a random order and it would be nice if the formula finds that P1 on column X (table 1) is multiplied by the corresponding P1 value for RM on Row Y (table 3).

Comment: @D.Nijland, it worked for your sample data :). That was the information we were given by you so that's what the answer is based on I'm afraid.

Comment: thank you it was already very helpful. The only difference I am talking about is as shown in the picture; where the columns of table 1 can be changed per situation (due to a pivottable). Therefore, it needs to look up the corresponding P in table 3 to multiply it.

Comment: I will use a VBA function to circumvent the issue. Now table 3 will be sorted similar to the column of Table 1 such that you can always multiply with the transposed array of table 1.